# Maintain one Instance of an Activity with SingleTop behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity

I want below behavior:

**Task 1:**

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C (Activity C is singleTop)

**Task 2:**

Activity D -> Activity E - Activity C

Here what I want is:

1. I want singleTop behaviour of Activity C i.e. No matter which task
   is shown, Activity C should be on top when I launch it from Recent
   Key(Task Manager)
2. There should be only one instance maintained i.e. when I do any
   changes in Task 2 Activity C, and I go to Task 1, what changes I did
   in Task 2 in Activity C should reflect here.

Is it possible?